# Custom Page Numbering in LyX (for thesis requirement)

Tags: lyx, page-numbering

I would like to place the page number in the top right corner of my page (inside the margin). My margins are 1 inch from the top and 1 inch from the right. I can put page numbers in the upper right corner by using a horizontal fill, but I would like the page number to be as close to my margin as possible. When I print out the document it is over 1.5 inches from the top of the page. How can I make the number appear higher in the page?

**MWE**
My source code for the following LyX screen and pdf is

```
\begin{center}
\newpage{}\hfill{}\hfill{}1\thispagestyle{empty}\vspace{1in}
\par\end{center}
\section{\noindent {\normalsize{INTRODUCTION}}}
```

My LyX screen is [image]

And my PDF is [image]

Comment: You might want to have a look at `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter`, and friends.

Comment: Pages that should have their numbers not typed (title, copyright, dedication?) would generally use `\thispagestyle{empty}` to remove the numbers.  They would still increment the count, however, which seems to be as desired.

Comment: @cslstr if I insert that in my Latex preamble, how will it know which page numbers to hide?

Comment: @TheSubstitute: Insert the command at the places of the corresponding pages, not in the preamble. You have to do this multiple times, at all positions/pages you don't want to have visually numbered.

Comment: thank you, this takes care of the pages that I don't want to have visible numbers.

Comment: I think this should have been 2 questions. It is now really confusing as the comments appear to bear no relation to the current version of the question. Also, please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) which people can use to recreate the issue and play with solutions. Right now, we don't even know which class you are using and that certainly affects the best choice of strategy.

Comment: The other questions were answered. Perhaps if this questions is resolved I can place the other questions back in here.

Comment: @cfr My document class is "article."

Comment: The question is supposed to be useful to other users - not just you. How is somebody to find those answers if you have deleted the question so that they cannot find it? Also, please provide an MWE.

Comment: By clicking on "editing x days ago", I can easily edit the question  once it has been answered so that it can appeal to a larger audience.

Comment: Don't format section headings manually. `\noindent` is unneeded and size/font changes should be declared globally in the preamble. Certainly don't format your page numbers like that. You need to use proper layout commands to get anything like reasonable results. Your page number should not be within the body of the text at all! Try `fancyhdr` with `geometry`. For section titles I always do it manually but others seem not to experience problems using `titlesec` although it never works for me. If you need more help, please post an MWE. That is not an MWE. See the link above for details.

Comment: "You need to use proper layout commands to get anything like reasonable results." That's profound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Page Margins set margins to 1 in. (you may need to adjust to get it exactly right).
In Page Layout set headings style to default.
In Preamble

```
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markboth{}{}
```

Add a thin space and a vertical space if you want the introduction to be a little down.

Page numbers should appear at right edge, starting at 1 on first page.

After that, I believe you can put a

```
\pagestyle{empty}
```

or otherwise, to remove the page numbers...

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.0.8 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markboth{}{}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
~ \vspace{3in}



\section{Introduction}

\lipsum

\lipsum
\pagestyle{empty}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```